# Download assets in it's original format in AEM

Tags: download, assets, aem, dam

I want to download the asset in it's original format using AEM, is it possible? Currently, if I select one pdf or jpeg asset, and click download, it's downloaded as a zip file which includes the selected asset. Now I want to download it without a container zip, that's to say download it in it's original format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to PDF then that's how the download for PDF works because when a PDF is uploaded all it's contents are extracted as sub-assets. This behaviour can be changed via modifying the PDF extraction logic but it won't affect the download behaviour.

The logic behind this is that when an artefact is uploaded in AEM it becomes a DAM asset and rules governing to it's manipulation take over. For example, in case of PDF, a PDF asset is a collection of the original PDF and all it's images and thumbnail extractions. So when you are downloading something you are basically downloading the whole collection as AEM sees it.

Having said that, you can probably write a custom servlet and extend the DAM GUI to download just the PDF.

Comment: Yes, I plan to write a custom servlet to download the asset in it's original format, but if the email checkbox is checked, the download should not take place, and an email should be sent out, user receives this mail and click the link should trigger the download procedure, this can't be controlled by the servlet. So this change may cause the behaviour between download via email and  download via webpage to be different. it seems not make sense

Comment: You can control the servlet behaviour by additional parameters can't you?

Comment: thanks, i found an useful page, it could solve my problem. http://www.computepatterns.com/153/overriding-out-of-the-box-servlet-in-aem-sling/

Answer (score 0):

You can select the option as shown below, when selecting 'Download' action after selecting the asset to download, in Assets UI

[image]